# apache settings to redirect web url to local host for testing

Tags: html, apache, localhost, http-redirect

I'm sure this is out there but for the life of me I can't find it. Probably b/c it's so simple and obvious and I'm just missing it. I have all of my css, includes, and php files referenced by relative paths on my local testing server and the same file structure on my web server so they are in sync. But how can I tell my local server to redirect any link in my html to say "c:\wamp\test_server\" instead of going to the actual link like "www.example.com"? That way the links will work in both environments AND I don't have to go back and change all of them. But then I would have to turn my web server off when I want to check the live site so it doesn't redirect to my local machine?

Any ideas? What is the de facto solution that everyone uses? I promise I have spent way too much time looking for the answer to this so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most commonly used solution here is to only use relative URLs in your code, not absolute URLs. If you don't mention the domain for the live site in your code, it won't be accessed.

For example, instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/blah/style.css">
```

Use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blah/style.css">
```

Comment: That is exactly how I reference my stylesheet and includes. The problem is if I want to include a link on a page to another page on my site. I prefer to use "http://www.example.com/article2" for SEO purposes and in case the location of the original page is changed, it will always point to the correct page in the link. But when testing, I use "127.0.0.1/wamp/site....." so I can traverse through my site on my home server easily. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You can still link to pages within your site using relative links like `/article2`. Search engines are not as stupid -- the type of link you use internally has no effect on ranking.